# GCC inline assembly in Linux bootc.c: Assembler messages: Error: junk 'int 0x10h' after expression

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm trying to compile c file via gcc and getting
Error

```
gcc -m32 -c bootc.c -o bootc.o
bootc.c: Assembler messages:
bootc.c:5: Error: junk `int 0x10h' after expression
```

Code

```
void kmain(void){
    asm(
        "mov %al, 'H'"
        "int 0x10h"
    );
}
```

Comment: On top of the answer provided: Unless this code is running in real mode, or is in a VM8086 task it won't work. The BIOS interrupt calls aren't available in 32-bit protected mode. You might consider a compiler like Bruce's C Compiler (`bcc`) or Alexy Frunzes Smaller C compiler that can properly deal with 16-bit code. Using GCC for 16-bit code is problematic. An example of a 2 stage bootloader using GCC can be found here: http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/ircasm/gccboot-2stage/ . It is proof of concept, very messy, and not recommended if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: If you are brave and want to write 16-bit code with GCC there is the gcc-ia16 project here: https://github.com/tkchia/gcc-ia16 . I personally have't used it and can't vouch for its usefulness or whether it is buggy.

Answer (score 3):

The inline assembly in GCC are normal literal strings, following the normal rules of such in C or C++ (whatever you're programming).

That means adjacent literal strings with nothing but space or comments between them will be *concatenated* into single strings.

What you think is

```
asm(
    "mov %al, 'H'"
    "int 0x10h"
);
```

is from the compilers perspective really

```
asm(
    "mov %al, 'H' int 0x10h"
);
```

The above is not a valid instruction.

That's why, if you look at many examples of GCC inline assembly, there needs to be newlines after each and every assembly line. As in

```
// also converted to Extended Asm syntax to fix other problems
asm(
    "mov $'H', %%al\n"  // Note newline here at the end
    "int $0x10"        // gas doesn't understand trailing-h suffix, only 0x for hex
    : // no outputs
    : // no inputs
    : "ax"  // tell the compiler we clobber AX
     // FIXME: also tell the compiler about any other registers this uses
);
```

The literal strings will still be concatenated, but now there's a newline between the instructions for the assembler to distinguish them.  It's common to use `\n\t` so the compiler's asm output is readable and indented normally.

---

On a related note, you really should learn more about [the AT&T/GAS assembly syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax), because there are other problems with your code. For example, numeric literals in assembly code needs to be prefixed with `$`; And there's no hexadecimal *suffix* for hexadecimal numbers, just the plain `0x` prefix (using both prefix and suffix `h` is redundant).

Also note that AT&T syntax has destination last, so moving the immediate value `'H'` into AL is done with `mov $'H', %al`.

Don't forget to set AH to a function code according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H.  The compiler could do anything it wanted with AH.

Comment: @PeterCordes : It should be `%%al` if in extended inline assembly in this case

Comment: @MichaelPetch: good catch, fixed.  Ugh, it's hard to answer questions with multiple problems in the same statement, but I really think this is a better answer if it not only compiles but also assembles, and doesn't clobber registers without telling the compiler.  As you commented on the question, though, `int $0x10` from gcc-compiled code is probably not good.  And definitely not with `-m32`, so that's another problem that isn't really addressed.

Comment: In addition to what Mr. Dude says, OP should also get comfortable using -S to view the actual assembler output being generated.  This can become particularly important when passing input and output constraints.